# Cocoa Swift: Save multiple NSImage files to the chosen url or path WITH the sandbox on

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have been able to get one image to save to a selected url but I need to save multiple NSImages with custom names. I would have preferred to save all the images into a directory then save the directory but I cant save anything to the directory after it is made. This is the code I have to save the single image from a NSSavepanel. (image1 is an NSImage(). It has been set to a file dragged and dropped into the app. Then it is resized).

```
func save() {
        let dialog = NSSavePanel()

        dialog.title = "Save file"
        dialog.showsResizeIndicator = false
        dialog.canCreateDirectories = true
        dialog.showsHiddenFiles = true
        dialog.allowedFileTypes = ["png"]

        if (dialog.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
            let result = dialog.url

            if (result != nil) {

                let picture = image1
                picture.writePNG(toURL: result!)
                print("saved at \(result!)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Cancel")
            return // User clicked cancel
        }

    }
```

This is the code I have to write the image to the url:

```
public extension NSImage {
    public func writePNG(toURL url: URL) {

        guard let data = tiffRepresentation,
            let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: data),
            let imgData = rep.representation(using: .png, properties: [.compressionFactor : NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1.0)]) else {

                print("\(self.self) Error Function '\(#function)' Line: \(#line) No tiff rep found for image writing to \(url)")
                return
        }

        do {
            try imgData.write(to: url)
        }catch let error {
            print("\(self.self) Error Function '\(#function)' Line: \(#line) \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a Security Scoped Bookmark

Comment: What is the 'chosen url'?  If it points to a directory, then use `NSOpenPanel` instead of `NSSavePanel`.

Comment: @ElTomato I just want to open the NSSavePanel and choose a destination. Once the Okay button is pressed it will save 5 different images all will different names to that destination or URL. I can get it to save one image but not a custom name.

Comment: `NSSavePanel` gives access to the particular chosen URL nowhere else.

Comment: @vadian I want to save files not open them. I tried using the NSOpenPanel. It only selects an image. How would you save multiple images to the url chosen in the NSSavePanel?

Comment: I didn't mention `NSOpenPanel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `NSOpenPanel` to obtain a destination folder from your user. Set the options so that the user can only select folders and can create new folders. You will get returned a URL to the existing or newly created folder. You can now create as many files (and subfolders) as you wish within the folder.

Comment: Thanks! After implementing what you said it now works. I appreciate it.